# Changing a list outside of the scope

Tags: python, list, scope

I'm trying to remove an item from a list , like so:

```
TodoList=[{'ID':5,'TodoItem':'walk','isDone':False}];

def RemoveItem(ID):
     if not any(todoItem['ID'] == ID for todoItem in TodoList):
          return 'item does not exist';

     RemovedList=list(filter(lambda todoItem:todoItem['ID']!= ID,TodoList))
     TodoList=RemovedList
```

does not work, I also tried this:

```
 def RemoveItem(ID):
         nonlocal TodoList
         if not any(todoItem['ID'] == ID for todoItem in TodoList):
              return 'item does not exist';

         TodoList=list(filter(lambda todoItem:todoItem['ID']!= ID,TodoList))
```

does anyone know whats the problem?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Also, I hope you realize that your initial `TodoList` is a dictionary but then RemovedList is mapped to a list. Can you provide a working code which people can copy paste and try running

Comment: im sorry, I fixed it, its a list containing a dictionary, and I get an error in the first one, TodoList' referenced before assignment and the second one, TodoList is not bound.

Comment: `TodoList[0].pop('ID', None)` should do the trick.

Comment: how does it should work if the `TodoList` not exists inside the function and should give you the `UnboundLocalError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible fix.

Passing the todo list (list of dict) as parameter, so it mutates:

```
TodoList=[{'ID':5,'TodoItem':'walk','isDone':False}, {'ID':6,'TodoItem':'talk','isDone':True}]

def RemoveItem(ID, TodoList):
     if not any(todoItem['ID'] == ID for todoItem in TodoList):
          print('item does not exist');
     else:
      for item in TodoList:
        if item['ID']== ID: TodoList.remove(item)


RemoveItem(5, TodoList)

print(TodoList)
#=> [{'ID': 6, 'TodoItem': 'talk', 'isDone': True}]
```

---

For your solution to work you need to return:

```
def RemoveItem(ID, TodoList):
     if not any(todoItem['ID'] == ID for todoItem in TodoList):
          return 'item does not exist';
     else:
      return list(filter(lambda todoItem:todoItem['ID']!= ID, TodoList))


print(RemoveItem(5, TodoList))
#=> [{'ID': 6, 'TodoItem': 'talk', 'isDone': True}]
```

This is because the line `list(filter(lambda todoItem:todoItem['ID']!= ID, TodoList))` doesn't mutate the list, it extracts elements based on condition.

But it is better to return the list itself if there is no item to delete, instead of returning a string.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to alt the TodoList without returning a new item..

Comment: Ok, but this line does not mutate the list, it just extract the elements which comply with the condition: `print(list(filter(lambda todoItem:todoItem['ID']!= 5, TodoList)))`. So you need to stick with something like my first snippet or one like @Daniel Mesejo

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to find the index of the item with id and use [pop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
todo_list = [{'ID': 5, 'TodoItem': 'walk', 'isDone': False}]


def remove_item(ID):
    if not any(todoItem['ID'] == ID for todoItem in todo_list):
        return 'item does not exist'

    # get index of id
    idx = next(i for i, e in enumerate(todo_list) if e['ID'] == ID)

    # remove and return
    return todo_list.pop(idx)


print(remove_item(4))
print(remove_item(5))
print(todo_list)
```

**Output**

```
item does not exist
{'isDone': False, 'ID': 5, 'TodoItem': 'walk'}
[]
```

The problem with your first attempt is that when you do: `TodoList=RemovedList` inside of a function, it creates a new local variable inside the function, even if there is a global variable with the same name. In your second attempt, you need to set to global instead of nonlocal:

```
todo_list = [{'ID': 5, 'TodoItem': 'walk', 'isDone': False}]

def RemoveItem(ID):
    global todo_list
    if not any(todoItem['ID'] == ID for todoItem in todo_list):
        return 'item does not exist';

    todo_list = list(filter(lambda todoItem: todoItem['ID'] != ID, todo_list))


RemoveItem(5)
print(todo_list)
```

**Output**

```
[]
```

**Further**

1. Documentation on [global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)